# Add files to zip using 7zip (or any tool) with MODIFIED/Created date in search criteria

Tags: command-line, zip, sql-server, 7-zip

I found couple of answers but most of them are focusing on adding the files that are named with date or timestamp within name (prefix/suffix), which i'm currently handling with following command.

This command is part of a procedure and procedure executed by SQL Job step to create a `.7z` file per day that include all the backups generated within day:

```
set @SearchKey = '20191015';

select @ZipCommand = ('C:\7-Zip\7z.exe a -p<mypassword> "' + @BackupPath + @ZipName + '" "' + @BackupPath + '*' + @SearchKey + '*.bak" ');
```

**The issue**: It works fine as long as the files created/named with current date-time, but some cases the file created with `name_timestamp`, and timestamp is based on UTC time, therefore the file name shows YESTERDAY but actual file belongs TODAY (following screenshot for the reference):

**Question**: Is there any possibility to define search criteria (in zip command) to find the files that are created/modified on particular date (not named with date)

[image]

Comment: No. Pipe files list to be compressed from `FORFILES /D`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that i will have a look